# How to add item(s) to a list box from a drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, listbox

I'm trying to add items from a drop down list (list populated from sql server) to a list box in asp.net (web form). The first item adds with no problem but that's it. When selecting the second item from the drop down, nothing happens. This is the code used in the drop down's SelectedIndexChanged event:

Both the drop down and the listbox have AutoPostBack set to true. What else is there to do? Shouldn't it be this simple:

```
 protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
 EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(DropDownList.SelectedItem);
    }

                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true"     
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
Visible="true"></asp:DropDownList>


<asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listBox" CssClass="form-control" 
AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"></asp:ListBox>
```

I need each item that is selected to be added to the listbox - not just the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Event convert the text into string.

```
protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBox.Items.Add(DropDownList.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Or if you have any other problem, let me know then.